# Importing data from Flat file

Tags: database, import, etl

I have two flat files via FTP. They’re in a directory on a file  share. I need to get them into an empty database on the same network.What will be the most efficient way to do it ?

Comment: 1 time? Reoccurring? what database? File Size? How many records?  Too little info will result in a too opinionated answer.  E.g. if each file is 1 record, manually keying seems most efficient especially if it's one time. if it's a reoccuring process, a program seems called for.  if one time, some RDBMS support import techniques and no program is needed.  Or you could load into excel generate and then use it to generate a script to run insert statements for all rows.  It also depends on what other tools you have.  It probably wouldn't be efficient to have to learn a new one...

Comment: Personally most RDBMS tools have a "Import" option which for 1 time load would seem to be the most efficent.  For example in SQL developer, you can create a new table from an import...  Similar features exist in SQL server Management Studio, Toad, and I would believe mySQL DB2 etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).